# i want to check user parameters. if its success i want to add to users array

Tags: javascript, node.js

there is error in my response. when i leave email and password empty my response shows correct error but when all fields are correct or i entered same email again it shows undefined. ihave also added my user file where i am checking user

```
router
  .route("/register")
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.render("register", { message: "" });
  })
  .post((req, res) => {
    const user ={
      email : req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    }

    checkUser =  new User
    const response = checkUser.registration(user)
    console.log(response)

  });
```

this is user file where i am checkin for errors

```
const users =[]
const Joi = require('joi')

class User{

    registration(userDetails){
        const {value ,error} = validateUser(userDetails)
        if(error){
            return error.message
        }else{
            const user = users.find((u) =>{
                if(u.email === userDetails.email){
                    return  "user Exist"
                }else{
                   users.push(user)
                   return users
                }
            })
        }

    }
}

function validateUser(user) {
    const JoiSchema = Joi.object({
      email: Joi.string().email().min(5).max(50).required(),
      password: Joi.string().min(5).required(),
    }).options({ abortEarly: false });
  
    return JoiSchema.validate(user);
  }

module.exports = User
```

Comment: You should debug to check whether the email and password are actually in your body.

Answer (score 0):

I made some code refactoring to your code. check it now. I didn't execute your code on my side but i hope is find.

```
// Route.
router.route("/register")
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.render("register", { message: "" });
  })
    .post((req, res) => {
        const user = {
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        }

        const checkUser = new User();
        const response = checkUser.registration(user);
        console.log(response);
    });

// User 
class User {
    registration(userDetails){
        const {value ,error} = validateUser(userDetails)
        if (error) return { error: message}
        else {
            const user = users.find((u) => (u.email).toLowerCase() === (userDetails.email).toLowerCase());
            if (user) return  { error: "user Exist" }
            else {
                users.push(user);
                return { users: users }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this is working can you please explain the mistake i was doing @Rehan shah

Comment: please check answer if it's worked.. Thanks

Comment: basically you were doing you if else response wrong in User > registration() function....